# How to align picture top left in a table?

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment

is there a way to create a **table** with 2 columns,
in the left column should be some text,
in the right column should be a picture.

The problem is - to align both to the left, top corner. The image seems to be inserted as an inline object, so it pushes the text down, from the top.

```
                          _____________________
                         |                     |    
                         |                     |
Some text is pushed down |                     |
```

What i want is:

```
Some text is pushed down  _____________________
                         |                     |    
                         |                     |
                         |                     |
```

Here is the code:

```
\begin{tabular}{\textwidth}{ l l }
Some text & \includegraphics{images/image.png} \\
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The **adjustbox** is what's needed:

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Some text & \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[height=3cm,width=4cm]{p}}\\
...
\end{tabular}
```

With `valign=t` the picture is lowered in such a way that its final height is similar to the height of the surrounding text (the rest will stick below).

If you want that the top of the figure is on the baseline, use `valign=T`.

As the author of **adjustbox** comments, calling

```
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
```

the options provided by the package can go directly in the argument of `\includegraphics`, so

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Some text & \includegraphics[valign=T,height=3cm,width=4cm]{p}}\\
...
\end{tabular}
```

is good as well. Change the other options for your case.

Comment: Using `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` you can use most keys directly for `\includegraphics`, i.e. `\includegraphics[height=3cm,width=4cm,valign=t]{p}`. The `set depth` key might also be useful if the official depth should be changed afterwards. A package-less alternative to `valign=T` would be `\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[..]{..}}`.

Comment: The new v0.7 now also provides `\adjustimage{<key=value>}{<filename>}` as a shortcut for `\adjustbox{<key=value>}{\includegraphics{<filename>}}`. You can place all keys for `\includegraphics` also into `\adjustbox`.

Comment: FINALLY! I've been looking all over the web, and found many answers, but this is the only really easy and good one.

Answer (score 4):

A similar approach without [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) is to use `\raisebox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\begin{document}

Some text \includegraphics[height=3\baselineskip]{example-image} (bottom-aligned with baseline)

\medskip

Some text \raisebox{-\height}{%
  \includegraphics[height=3\baselineskip]{example-image}} (top-aligned with baseline)

\medskip

Some text \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\baselineskip}{%
  \includegraphics[height=3\baselineskip]{example-image}} (top-aligned with ``baselineskip'')

\end{document}
```

If the image is used inside a `tabular`, one may consider using `\raisebox{..}[0pt][0pt]{...}` to remove the depth/height of the object. This allows the object to overlap with content above/below it, depending on the usage.