# float left figure in titlepage

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles, wrapfigure

I try add a figure in the titlepage

```
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{figure}[h]
                \includegraphics[scale=0.15]{images/logo.jpg}
        \end{figure}                                                                                                                        
        Univ...\\
        fac ... 
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}
        {\large Title}\\
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

but text [univ...] is down of figure

the idea is get some similar to this

```
[figure][univ ...]

[title]
```

Comment: Have a look at [How to align picture top left in a table?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30079/how-to-align-picture-top-left-in-a-table).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a figure but only `\includegraphics`:

```
\begin{titlepage}
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-\height\relax}{\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{images/logo}}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.79\linewidth}
    Univers\dots
  \end{minipage}
  \vskip 2\baselineskip
  {\Large Titel\par}
\end{titlepage}
```

Here, if top aligned the text and the image, because using multi line text this is common and mostly asked. If you want the text beside the image be vertical centered to the image, you may use one more `minipage` and adjustes vertical alignment options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% remove option demo if you have images/logo

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \begin{minipage}[c]{.2\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/logo}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[c]{.7\linewidth}
    Univers\dots\\
    at somewhere\\
    under controll of someone
  \end{minipage}

  \vspace{2\baselineskip}
  \begin{center}
    \Large Titel
  \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Here I've used a horizontal centered title, to show more alternatives.

Alternative you may simply change vertikal alignment of images changing the first argument of `\raisebox` and the alignment option of the `minipage` with the text.

Another solution would be to use package [adjustbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) to add the vertical alignment option `valign` to the `\includegraphics` options. See the excellent manual of package adjustbox for more information. Some lines below you may even find an example of using the package.

One more alternative: If you are using a KOMA-Script class like scrartcl, it's very easy to do it, using `\titlehead`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% remove option demo if you have images/logo
\begin{document}
\titlehead{%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-\height\relax}{\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{images/logo}}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.78\linewidth}\raggedright
    Univers\dots\\
    at here\\
    with there
  \end{minipage}
}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

And if you don't use a KOMA-Script class but like that title, you may install [package titlepage](http://www.komascript.de/titlepage) (link destination in German!).

The `\raisebox` in these examples is used to move the baseline of the graphics from the bottom to almost the top of the graphics. An alternative solution for this would be using package [adjustbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) and add option `valign=t` to `\includegraphics`, if your adjustbox is up to date:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% remove option demo if you have images/logo
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\titlehead{%
  \includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth,valign=t]{images/logo}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.78\linewidth}\raggedright
    Univers\dots\\
    at here\\
    with there
  \end{minipage}
}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

If you want the titles of the KOMA-Script classes with, e.g., a standard class and installation of package [titlepage](http://www.komascript.de/titlepage) is to difficult, you may try package scrextend. This package is part of [KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script), which may be installed via package manager of almost every TeX distribution and often is already installed.

Here's the example above with standard class article but KOMA-Script title:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[extendedfeature=title]{scrextend}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% remove option demo if you have images/logo

\begin{document}
\titlehead{%
  \begin{minipage}[c]{.2\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/logo}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[c]{.7\linewidth}
    Univers\dots\\
    at somewhere\\
    under controll of someone
  \end{minipage}
}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

To show one more alternative, I've changed the vertical alignment of image text beside the image:

[image: Visualization of the example of Standard class with KOMA-Script title]

Comment: You can do it simpler: `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` and then `\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth,valign=t]{images/logo}`.

Comment: Simpler? Other.

Comment: Well, you save yourself a `\raisebox` and a calculation. `valign=t` does basically the exact same thing as the `\raisebox` you have it.

Comment: Yes, but what's simpler? To install the newest release of a package and remember it with all it's options or to use a well known LaTeX kernel macro? Never the less: I've voted for your comment, added your suggestion already to my answer and updated TeX Live at my (very old and slow) notebook.

Comment: It's simpler when you already have it installed and know about it :-) I wasn't saying your original code is bad or anything, or that you had to edit it. I just wanted to point out that there is a simpler solution for it now. Many beginners won't know about `\raisebox` or how to exactly calculate the correct shift. Using a package which provides a simple key for that is in fact simpler. That's all.

Comment: @Schweinebacke 1) when I use `\raisebox` the top of image is distorsionate. 2) with the text in `{minipage}[t]{.78\linewidth}` never is centered (I change the .78 to other values)

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: I've tried to use `valign=m` to center a image using vadjustbox. But this results in a `-.5` at the output instead changed vertical alignment. So I've used one more minipage to vertically center image and text. Please have look.

Comment: @JuanPablo: Should it be centered vertical or horizontal. I've added examples with vertical centering to my answer. Horizontal centering is more simple: Add `\centering` after the begin of the `minipage` but before the text.

Comment: `valign=m` does works fine with current version. Which version are you using?

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: 2011/10/30 v0.7, the version from my new TeX Live installation yesterday. If I simply change the `valign=t` to `valign=m` at my example above, I get the described wrong result. Hm, and know even `\documentclass{article}\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}\begin{document}\includegraphics[valign=top]{tost}\end{document}` results in `! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).` after `<tost.pdf, id=1, 597.50829pt x 845.0471pt> <use tost.pdf>`. Using additional `\adjustbox` instead of option to `\includegraphics` does work.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: Sorry not `valign=top` but `valign=t` results in the error. I'll ask my good friend Markus. Maybe he`ll find the problem ...

Comment: @Schweinebacke: I fixed that now in the develop version. There was an issue that math expressions aren't handled correctly when `\includegraphics` is used directly. There is also `\adjustimage{<keys>}{<image>}` which can be used instead of `\adjustbox{<keys>}{\includegraphics{<image>}}`.

Answer (score -1):

I solved with `\vspace`

```
\begin{titlepage}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.15]{images/logo.jpg}    
    \vspace{-2cm}
    \begin{center}
        Univer...\\
        fac ...
    \end{center}
    \vspace{4cm}                                                                                                                            
    \begin{center}
        {\large Title}\\
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: That's not a real solution but a very ugly hack, because figures may float. But you don't need a float and you should not use it at this place.

Comment: You don't need to and should not use `figure` here. You can use `\includegraphics` directly.

Comment: @MartinScharrer if I don't use `figure` the image is centered

Comment: If you don't want it to be centered, why do you use the `center` environment here?

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt ok, I deleted `center`

Comment: @JuanPablo: What's your problem with the several suggestions I've made in my answer?