# I cannot get an image and `lstlisting` aligned in a table

Tags: tables, graphics, listings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to align picture top left in a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30079/how-to-align-picture-top-left-in-a-table)

I want to display an image and some lines of monospaced text with line breaks (as far as I know, `lstlisting` is the only option). The upper bounds of both image and text should both be aligned at the top of the row, but I always result in either the image or the monospace text at the wrong position. As I don't understand whats wrong I haven't got any clue how to fix this.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
\lstset{
    breaklines     = true
}
\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{10cm}|}
\hline
\includegraphics{/Users/jenserat/Downloads/test.png} & \begin{lstlisting}
Some listing.
Some listing. Some lines can get quite long and should be wrapped.
Some listing.
Some listing.
Some listing.
Some listing.
Some listing.
Some listing.
\end{lstlisting} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I tried using different combinations of tabular, tabularx, graphics, graphicsx, minipages without luck. I want to avoid some ugly hacks using `vspace` as this latex code should be generated by some script which probably will get distributed.

I'd like to use a table, but am not bound to one. I do not mind using tabularx and do not mind what column style I use (as long as the code is left-aligned).

[image: Wrong display with hint how it should look like]

Comment: I'd be tempted to use `minipage`s with the optional alignment argument, either `t`, `b`, or `c`

Comment: Succeeded with `adjustbox` as proposed by @MartinScharrer - thanks a lot! `\begin{minipage}[t]{...}...\end{minipage}` didn't work in this case.

Comment: I will close as a duplicate, as suggested, especially because the solution of the answer to the linked question has solved this problem too, confirmed by the OP.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: FYI your comment has been automatically deleted when closing, probably automatism because of the link to the dupe.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz: Thanks. I will post two separate comments next time.