# Vertical centering in tabularx

Tags: vertical-alignment, tabularx

I am trying to get a text to center vertically within a `tabularx`. For centered and bottom text it works, but it fails for top text. What am I missing here?

```
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | X | c | }
            \hline
            \noindent\parbox[t]{\hsize}{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{img/image001}} & top\\
            \hline
            \noindent\parbox[c]{\hsize}{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{img/image001}} & center\\
            \hline
            \noindent\parbox[b]{\hsize}{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{img/image001}} & bottom\\
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `valign` from `adjustbox`.

I used also `margin=4pt` to put some space around the image, and I inverted the column types of your table, I don't think you want an `X` type for a column where there are only fixed-width images.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}\centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | c | X | }
            \hline
            \includegraphics[width=5cm, valign=t, margin=4pt]{example-image} & top\\
            \hline
            \includegraphics[width=5cm, valign=c, margin=4pt]{example-image} & center\\
            \hline
            \includegraphics[width=5cm,valign=b, margin=4pt]{example-image} & bottom\\
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Your question may be a duplicate of this one: [How to align picture top left in a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30079/how-to-align-picture-top-left-in-a-table).